# I want to get Fragment data in MainActivity calling fragment method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to show current weather data in fragment on search CityName base. Mean if I entered any city name in searchbox it show me the current weather of that city. All work was performing correctly if I give static City name, but I want that which city I select it give me this current data.

The SearchBox (EditText) is on Main Activity and currentweather data Method where I want to show my currentweather data is in Fragment. How it is possible to search on Main Activity and show currentweather data in fragment layout.

MainActivity

```
    package com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Adapter.FragementViewAdapter;
import com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Fragment.currentweather;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public static String BaseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/";
    public static String AppId = "08fd7374790f2ccee9f1f1dbfae38fdf";
    /* public static String lat = "33.69";
     public static String lon = "73.06";*/
    ViewPager viewPager;
    FragementViewAdapter fragementViewAdapter;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    EditText text_search;
    ImageButton btn_search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        text_search = findViewById(R.id.text_search_city);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        btn_search = findViewById(R.id.btn_search);

       final currentweather currentweather = new currentweather();
        btn_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                currentweather weather= (currentweather) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.current_weather);
                assert weather != null;
                weather.getCurrentData();
                   String City= text_search.getText().toString().trim();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("search_city", City);
                    currentweather.setArguments(bundle);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, currentweather).commit();
                    currentweather.getCurrentData();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(City)) {
                        text_search.setError("Enter City Name");
                        return;
                    }

            }
        });
        fragementViewAdapter = new FragementViewAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(fragementViewAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();


    }
}
```

CurrentWeatherFragment

```
    package com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.CurrentWeather.WeatherResponse;
import com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.R;
import com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Retrofit.WeatherService;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

import static com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.MainActivity.AppId;
import static com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.MainActivity.BaseUrl;

public class currentweather extends Fragment {

    public TextView text_country,text_city,text_pressure,text_humidity,text_temp;
    public TextView textView_country, textView_city, textView_temp,
            textView_pressure, textView_humidity, textview_date;
    /*public TextView text_view;*/
    public currentweather() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View itemview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currentweather, container, false);

            textView_country = itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView_country);
            textView_city =itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView_city);
            textView_temp =itemview.findViewById(R.id.textview_temp);
            textView_pressure =itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView_pressure);
            textView_humidity =itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView_humidity);
            textview_date =itemview.findViewById(R.id.textView_date);
            text_country= itemview.findViewById(R.id.text_country);
            text_city=itemview. findViewById(R.id.text_city);
            /*text_view=itemview.findViewById(R.id.text_view);*/
            text_pressure=itemview. findViewById(R.id.text_pressure);
            text_humidity=itemview.findViewById(R.id.text_humidity);
            text_temp=itemview.findViewById(R.id.text_temp);

           /* Bundle bundle=getArguments();
            if (bundle!=null)
            {
                city=bundle.getString("search_city");
                textView_country.setText(city);
                Log.d("ass",""+city);

            }*/
            text_country.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_city.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_pressure.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_humidity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text_temp.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return itemview;
    }
    public void getCurrentData() {
        String City1 = null;
        if (getArguments() != null){
            City1=getArguments().getString("search_city");
        }
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        WeatherService weatherService = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call = weatherService.getCurrentWeatherDataCityName(City1, AppId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    WeatherResponse weatherResponse = (WeatherResponse) response.body();
                    assert weatherResponse != null;
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-dd-MM");
                    String formatedate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                   /* String stringbuilder= "Country : " +
                            weatherResponse.sys.country +
                            "\n" +
                            "City : " +weatherResponse.name +
                            "\n" +
                            "Tempreture : " + weatherResponse.main.temp +
                            "\n" +
                            "Tempreture(Min) : " +
                            weatherResponse.main.temp_min +
                            "\n" +
                            "Tempreture(Max) : " +
                            weatherResponse.main.temp_max +
                            "\n" +
                            "Humidity : " +
                            weatherResponse.main.humidity +
                            "\n" +
                            "Pressure : " +
                            weatherResponse.main.pressure;*/
                    String Country = weatherResponse.sys.country;
                    String City = weatherResponse.name;
                    String Temp = String.valueOf(weatherResponse.main.temp);
                    Double calcius = Double.parseDouble(Temp) - 273.0;
                    Integer i = calcius.intValue();
                    String Pressure = String.valueOf(weatherResponse.main.pressure);
                    String Humidity = String.valueOf(weatherResponse.main.humidity);
                    textView_country.setText(Country);
                    textView_city.setText(City);
                    textView_temp.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                    textView_pressure.setText(Pressure);
                    textView_humidity.setText(Humidity);
                    textview_date.setText(formatedate);
                    text_country.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text_city.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text_pressure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text_humidity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text_temp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (response.code()==404)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "City Not Founded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                textView_country.setText(t.getMessage());
                textView_city.setText(t.getMessage());
                textView_temp.setText(t.getMessage());
                textView_pressure.setText(t.getMessage());
                textView_humidity.setText(t.getMessage());
                textview_date.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Currentweatherframent.XML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/current_weather"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_country"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_country"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_country" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="City"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_city"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_city" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_temp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:text="Temperature"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView_country"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_temp"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text_temp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_pressure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Pressure"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_temp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_pressure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_pressure" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_humidity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Humidity"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_pressure" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_humidity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_humidity" />-->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error

```
    1-03 19:35:10.586 1428-1428/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp, PID: 1428
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:107)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:264)
        at com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Fragment.currentweather$1.onResponse(currentweather.java:129)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
01-03 21:43:00.695 10885-10885/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp, PID: 10885
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp/com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Fragment.currentweather.getCurrentData()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.Fragment.currentweather.getCurrentData()' on a null object reference
        at com.deitel.apiretrofitfragmentweatherapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301)
```

Comment: Your `weather` object is null or `currentWeather` object is null.

Comment: how to solve it please can you give me a code hnt

Comment: You can enable assertions in the JVM or change `assert weather != null` to a if statement so when `weather == null` you don't call methods on the `weather` object.

Comment: okay sir thank you now it is working fine.again thanks